# Simple Commutator question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

For some reason this is really tripping me up:
$$[q_rq_sp_r,q_sp_rq_s]$$
Where $r$ and $s$ are different.  Is this just zero because $p_r$ on $q_s =0$.

I am trying to simplify this and I feel like 0 is too easy.

Comment: It is not zero. Use the relation $[AB,C]=A[B,C]+[A,C]B$ and the basic commutation rule to work it out. You'll see there will be only one nontrivial commutator, namely $[q_r,p_r]$

Comment: I did all those out and ended up with $i\hbar q_s^2p_r$ does this seem reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[q_r q_s p_r , q_s p_r q_s]=q_r [q_s p_r , q_s p_r q_s ] + [q_r q_s , q_s p_r q_s]p_r=q_r q_s [p_r , q_s p_r q_s ] + q_r[q_s , q_s p_r q_s]p_r + q_r [q_s , q_s p_r q_s ]p_r + [q_r , q_s p_r q_s]q_s p_r$

Now only the last term is non-vanish because the others three have inside the commutators only operators that commutes one to each other. So:

$[q_r q_s p_r , q_s p_r q_s]=[q_r , q_s p_r q_s]q_s p_r = q_s [q_r , p_r q_s]q_s p_r+[q_r , q_s p_r ]q_sq_s p_r= q_s p_r[q_r , q_s]q_s p_r+q_s [q_r , p_r ]q_sq_s p_r + q_s[q_r , p_r ]q_s q_s p_r+[q_r , q_s] p_r q_sq_s p_r$

For the same reason the first and the last addend are 0 (they commute). 
Using $[q_r,p_r]=i \hbar $ :

$[q_r q_s p_r , q_s p_r q_s]=q_s [q_r , p_r ]q_sq_s p_r + q_s[q_r ,  p_r ]q_sq_s p_r=2i \hbar q_s ^3 p_r$

This is the final result that it's not zero as you predict.